# ReactJS componentDidUpdate not called even after props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, draftjs

I'm working with draft-js for react where I make an api call (IN A FUNCTIONAL PARENT COMPONENT) and get contents to be put up in the editor. I have this code to insert the fetched data into the editor after receiving it in props:

Parent Component:

```
var draftContent = "";
var isContentFetched = false;

const CommentSection = () => {
      let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "get",
        headers: headers,
      });

      let query = await response.json(); // read response body and parse as JSON
      draftContent = element.comment;
      isContentFetched = true;
      return(<RichTextEditor
                isDraftFetched={isDraftFetched}
                isContentFetched={isContentFetched}
                placeholder=""
                rows={6}
                boxWidth="100%"
                boxHeight="155px"
              />)
})
```

Editor Component:

```
  componentDidUpdate(props) {
      if(this.props.isContentFetched == true && draftAlreadyFilled== false) {
        this._insertText(this.props.draftContent);
        draftAlreadyFilled = true;
      }
  }

 _insertText(htmlContent) {
    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
        ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
          convertFromHTML(htmlContent)
        )
      ),
    })
  }
```

Problem is, the text loaded and sent through props does not fill up in the editor. Instead once I am in the page and I click on refresh, then it loads fine.

PS: 1. I have checked related questions and those solutions did not work. 2. It is really necessary that I make the API call in the parent component.

Comment: have you tried using `useEffect` to wrap around your fetch request? It seems like the issue is that your DOM is not updating properly. Are you using `componentDidMount` or something else?

Comment: where does `element` come from?

Comment: I've tried useEffect @ZombieChowder

Comment: @messerbill sorry that was `query.comment`

Comment: *Instead once I am in the page and I click on refresh, then it loads fine.* how do you refresh the page? by clicking the browser's refresh button?

Comment: Yes @messerbill

Comment: then we need to know when and how the `CommentSection` is rendered

Comment: `CommentSection` is rendered with router using history.push("/commentsSection?id=someId") and id is got back from url while sending it to api. @messerbill